# Strange behaviour of custom drag and drop function

Tags: vuejs2, electron

I'm currently creating an electron application (Frontend is in Vue) which can trigger native Drag-and-Drop-Operations. These Operations behave strange if i trigger them with HTML5 Drag Events (like dragstart, dragstop, etc.). So I have to implement my own Drag-and-Drop Handler using mouseup, mousedown and mousemove. So in simple theory:

> If MouseDown is triggered -> Set Flag
>
> If MouseUp is triggered -> Remove Flag
>
> If MouseMove AND Flag -> checkCurrentPosition vs. initialPosition -> Do something

```
new Vue({
el: "#app",
  data: {
    mousedown: false
  },
  methods: {
    onMouseDown: function(e){
        console.log('mousedown');
        this.mousedown = true;
    },
    onMouseUp: function(e){
        console.log('mouseup');
        this.mousedown = false;
    },
    onMouseMove: function(e){
            if(this.mousedown) {
        console.log('mousedown && mousemove');
        console.log('clientX:', e.clientX);
        console.log('clientY:', e.clientY);
      }
    },
  }
})
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rqs2zdng/3/)

if you check this example, open up your browsers console and play a little bit around with the image (click, drag and drop,...) you will see that if you drag the placeholder image, the mousedown event is triggered and the flag is set. Then I would expect that the mousemove event would be triggered frequently, but this is not happening.

Normally if you bind mousemove to some Div its triggered frequently if you hover with your mouse over it and you can get the actual position  for example. But this is not happening after mousedown.

NOTE: The mouseup event in the Fiddle is not bound to Window, so if you Drop the Element outside of its area the mouseup event will not be triggered for the element. So the flag is not removed and then you can see the behaviour I would expect. the mousemove event is frequently triggered. So I think that the problem is that while the mouse is pressed the mousemove event is not triggered correctly.

Comment: This is how they are suppose to behave, after dragging the element a new ghost image is created by the html which is not the same element where your mouse event listeners are attached. I would suggest that you stick to drag and drop related events provided by html and try resolving problems you are facing in it instead of using mouse events which has altogether different functionality. If you have trouble using vanilla drag drop you can use jquerys drag and drop as well.

Comment: Thank you. I checked my old code which was using the DOM Drag Events. It turned out that my problem here was that I was not preventing defaults... Which lead to a constellation where DOM Dragstart was triggered and afterwards electrons native dragstart was triggered. I think there where inteferrencing with each other, so preventing defaults helped me to only trigger the native electron drag.